# How to Make a Leaderboard System in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, leaderboard

I am an Eighth Grader and I am trying to make a leaderboard program using Google Spreadsheets that calculates how many different states a certain class has gotten. I don't know how to make it so that it will `COUNTUNIQUE` the number of times that a certain class has another unique state that a donation has come from. I know how to make the part of the leaderboard that displays the results, but I need help in the part that calculates how many different states (ie: FL, GA, TN, AK) a certain teacher/classroom has at once, which I can then order from highest to lowest and use `QUERY` to drop it into my leaderboard. Hope that one of you can help!

[Here is an example of the spreadsheet I want to order by teacher and state](https://docs.google.com/a/wrsmail.net/spreadsheets/d/1HYayXhryad-zaPsmdRqhr-p_6I06h9-pnIVBVvUcqy0/edit#gid=0).

Comment: show us sample data (best in tabular format). describe the SPECIFFIC problem you have and what you have so far and what you have tried. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are the results you are looking for:

[image: SO26394513 example]

then a pivot table should suit, with `Teacher` added to Rows, `State/Province/Region/County/Territory/Prefecture/Republic` added to  Values and Summarise by: COUNTUNIQUE.

Comment: I know how to do countunique. I need to make it order by how high the number is, though.

Comment: Also, that doesn't help me, because I don't know how to make a pivot table. Could you include that in your answer?